# Creating a new Outlook email from a text file

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'd like to be able to create a new email from a text file (e.g. a .html file or a text file containing the full email text including headers), and either open it as a draft or send it immediately from my main Exchange account using Outlook 2007.

Is this possible? How'd I go about doing it?

What I'd really like is an equivalent to Linux's `sendmail`, but plugging in to Outlook to arrange mail delivery, and possibly with a way of viewing the draft email before sending it.

**Update**: I've managed to get the functionality I want by tracking down an SMTP server in my office, and plumbing into Cygwin's `email`. Not ideal (I really can't do anything useful like this with Outlook from the command line‽) but that's the way this rolls, apparently.

Comment: Is it a requirement to use files? Or you just want to have a quick way to insert full email text?

Comment: @thims: Using files is a requirement: the content I want to email will be output automatically to a file, with HTML formatting in place. I'm happy enough writing scripts to manipulate that file into some other format (e.g. adding email headers), but opening the HTML file in a browser and copy-pasting the content into an email is too many manual steps.